# Truncate existing table within a stored procedure then insert fresh data

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, ssms

I have a stored procedure that returns a result set. After that I insert this result set into created real table. And then I am using that real table create SSRS reports.

So, something like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test
AS
   DECLARE @TempTable TABLE(..)

   INSERT INTO @TempTable
       SELECT...
       FROM ...
       WHERE ...

SELECT * FROM @TempTable

--============================

INSERT INTO RealTable EXEC [dbo].[Test]
```

How can I modify this stored procedure so every time it executed it will truncate table with existing data and then insert a fresh one?

So I need something like that:

```
create procedure Test
as
TRUNCATE RealTable
DECLARE @TempTable TABLE(..)

INSERT INTO @TempTable
    SELECT...
    FROM...
    WHERE...

SELECT * FROM @TempTable INTO RealTable
```

Or should I just create agent job that would run command something like:

```
Truncate Table RealTable
INSERT INTO RealTable EXEC [dbo].[Test]
```

Am I on a right way in terms of logic?

Comment: Seems **VERY** dangerous - if two users hit it at the same time one user will wipe out the other's results.  Seems like a table with a session ID column or some other method would be safer.

Comment: You don't need to populate the temp table you could go straight to the real table. Also you need to be aware that truncate table is only possible if there are no Foreign Key home to the table

Comment: Users are not running this report. I am the one who deploys it on a weekly base and send it via emails.

Comment: So where should I say Truncate table in my stored procedure?

Comment: At any point before the insert.  So the flow is like this: `CREATE SP AS ... TRUNCATE TABLE ... INSERT INTO RealTable SELECT ... FROM ... WHERE ...`'.

Comment: Thanks.
Another thing, would it be more convenient to create agent job that would execute stored procedure on a weekly base? Something like that:
'Truncate Table RealTable
INSERT INTO RealTable EXEC [dbo].[Test]'

Answer (score 0):

1. What's the purpose of the truncate if you are inserting the same data?
2. What should happen if you have more then  1 concurrent user?

another thing you can do:
1.
insert into TargetTable
select * from SourceTable
2.
rebuild indexes on TargetTable
3.
exec sp_rename SourceTable, SourceTable_Old
exec sp_rename TargetTable, SourceTable
drop table SourceTable_Old

- this is an old way of entire table data refresh without much impact, when table variable was not an option.

Comment: The purpose of truncating is to refresh the data. Then on a weekly base run a report out of that data.
I am the only one who deploys a report and sends it to particular emails. Nobody is gonna run a report without my permission

Comment: several concerns:
1. put it in transaction, so no updates on a table will be done
2. while using table variable, you fill it the tempdb - may cause other problems (space,locking)
3. after inserting data, rebuild all indexes will full scan, statistics need to be updated.

Answer (score 0):

Dont TRUNCATE. Use a MERGE Statement.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE Test
AS

MERGE RealTable TRGT
USING SourceTable SRCE
    ON SRCE.[Column] = TRGT.Column --use columns that can be joined together
WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE
        SET TRGT.Column1 = SRCE.Column1,
            TRGT.Column2 = SRCE.Column2
        ....................
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY TARGET THEN INSERT
        VALUES
        (
            SRCE.Column1,
            SRCE.Column2,
            .....................
        )
WHEN NOT MATCHED BY SOURCE THEN 
        DELETE;
```

Comment: Care to explain why?

Answer (score 0):

this is what you probably need as you are directly inserting from @TempTable to RealTable.

```
create procedure Test
as
BEGIN

TRUNCATE TABLE RealTable

INSERT INTO RealTable 
    SELECT...
    FROM someothertable
    WHERE...

END
```